# How to get values one by one from query result and Pass that as a parameter to another query and loop it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I will fetch values from the below query. Then I will create a loop.

```
select a FROM [tbl_outer] where col=1
```

Using the above loop, I need to fetch values from the below query (F.a = a)

```
select Distinct C.v, F.a
from tbl_main as F
    join tbl_inner1  as C on C.ID = F.ID and c.to = 0 
    join tbl_inner2 as E on E.a = F.a
    join tbl_inner3 as G on G.Id = E.Sales
where F.a = a
  and C.v NOT IN(select v from table_4
                 where Month = DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
                   AND Year = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()))
```

How do I do that ? Could you please help me.

Comment: The term "loop" is a bit confusing here. Do you mean that you want, for each row returned by your first query, fetch the values from the second query ? Also, in the final result, do you want to have all the rows of the first query, even if the second query returns nothing for them (outer join) ? Or, do you want to keep only values where the second query returns something (inner join) ?

Comment: Yes based on the Result of First query i will pass that Result to second query and After executing second query need to go to the first query  and then select the second row from the result.. I want the values where the second query returns something

Comment: Are the tables `tbl_outer` and `tbl_innerX` in the same database? If not, are the databases on the same server?

Comment: Yes, they are in same database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables are all on the same database, you can try this out (unfortunately I cannot test it right now, but I'm quite sure it will work):

```
select T.cv, T.fa, a
FROM [tbl_outer] 
left outer join (
    select Distinct C.v as cv, F.a as fa
    from tbl_main as F
    join tbl_inner1 as C on C.ID = F.ID and c.to = 0 
    join tbl_inner2 as E on E.a = F.a
    join tbl_inner3 as G on G.Id = E.Sales
    where C.v NOT IN(select v from table_4
                     where Month = DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
                     AND Year = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()))
) T on a = T.fa
where col=1
```

**Explanation**

- I've used a [`left outer join`](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join) to keep all the values returned by your first query.
- For each row returned by your first query, this will fetch the data from your second query.
- If your second query doesn't return anything for a given row of your first query, the corresponding column values (i.e. `T.cv` and `T.fa` here) will be `NULL`
- I've used a few aliases for the columns in your second query to avoid any potential confusions for the column names in the outer query

This query can surely be optimised, but let's confirm the correctness first.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add in an additional `join` condition:

```
select Distinct C.v, F.a
from tbl_outer o join
     tbl_main f
     on f.a = o.a join
     tbl_inner1 C
     on C.ID = F.ID and c.to = 0 join
     tbl_inner2 E
     on E.a = F.a join
     tbl_inner3 G
     on G.Id = E.Sales
where o.col = 1 and 
      C.v not in (select v
                  from table_4 t4
                  where t4.Month = month(getdate()) and t4.year = year(getdate())
                 );
```

Notes:

- This replaces `datepart()` with the more understandable `month()` and `year()` functions.
- All column names are qualified.
- You may want `left join`s if you want to keep all matching `o.a`s, even those with no other matching values.